# UIViewController - mysterious blank on top and bottom with iPad Pro 3rd

Tags: objective-c, swift, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a problem about UIViewController by iPad Pro 3rd.

[Screenshot: First screen on iPad pro 3rd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1LtU.jpg)

It appear first screen there are blanks on top(under status bar) and bottom(with home bar).

I try to remove there but never.

I'd appreciate if you would provide me a good solution.

Thank you.

Comment: can you share your code ?

Comment: Have you tried toying with the safe area? New iPad pros have rounded corners, and a different safe area than the previous ones

Answer (score 0):

Change the Contraints to align to match the top and bottom of your view. Screenshot shows a view which looks ok for iphone. For ipad pro you will have to change the top and bottom constraints.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Which Xcode version you are using? Building the app in Xcode 10.1 may resolve the issue. Apps build with older Xcode runs in compatibility mode where View size does not match for the new device.